# Denote if string contains any member of a set of characters

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, computer-science

I come from a computer science background and trying to properly document the following python if statement.

```
for char in X:
    if char in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
        return true
        break
```

Here I am checking if the string contains any of the alphabet characters. No matter the position or frequency, it's true as long as X contains any member of `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`. When `X = "hello"` is true. `X = "123"` is false. And `X = "hello 123"` is true.

How would I mathematically denote this? I don't think the following is possible as it checks if the *entire* $X$ sequence is a member of $g$.

$g = \{a, b, c, \dots, z\}$

***if $X \in g$ then***

Would it be a subset? ***if $X \subset g$ then***

Preferably I wouldn't have to denote the character loop as it's an unimportant detail. Just if the string contains any alphabet character

Comment: Uh.... your python is incorrect as well for what you are describing... `X in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"` would only return true if $X$ is a string consisting exclusively of consecutive lowercase letters.  `"lmnop"` would return true, `"hello"` would return false... `"ABC"` would return false.  `"lmnop 123"` would also return false.

Comment: You're correct, I wrote too concise. I'm looping over all characters in the string. So X is actually a single character of a string. Something I dont need explicitly detailed. Rather if the string contains any alphabet characters.

Comment: Well... if $X$ is actually just a single character, then $X\in g$ would be fine... we are usually quite liberal in terms of how we interpret mathematical objects... for example at times treating the number $1$ as the natural number $\{\emptyset\}$, other times as the integer $[(1,0)]\in\Bbb N/\sim$, other times as the real number $(-\infty,1]$, going back and forth between interpretations without explicitly saying so... a sequence of characters of length $1$ might as well have been thought of as a character itself...

Comment: Thank you, good to understand that. How would I denote it if $X$ is still the entire string? If any of the elements (characters) of string X is a member of the character set $g$. I edited my question if that helps.

Comment: If $X$ is a string of multiple characters, then you can interpret $X$ as "$x_1x_2x_3\dots x_n$" where each $x_i$ is an individual character in the string $X$ and write the statement "There is an alphabetic character in $X$" as $\exists i~x_i\in\text{Alphabet}$.  There are surely dozens of other valid ways to write this, this is just one of the first that came into my head.

Comment: Thank you. Makes a lot of sense. Would I have to explain $x_1$? as so far I only mentioned X. That it's actually $x_1, x_2, x_3 \dots x_n$ ? Or would it be interpreted correctly? If you could submit it as answer I can accept it.

Comment: Excuse me, but are this question and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3598268) one really from different users?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would rather use $A$ (for *alphabet*) for the set $\{a, b, c, \dots, z\}$ and $C$ for the set of all characters (char). With this notation, a string $s$ of $C^*$ satisfies your condition if and only if $s \in C^*AC^*$.
In other words, your condition can be mathematically represented by a [regular language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language).

Answer (score 0):

Let s be a string, S the set of the symbols in s,
and A the set of all letters of the alphabet.

That s contains a letter is expressed
S $\cap$ A is not empty.